# Display placeholder if array is empty

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have this html code

```
  <empty-list [hidden]="!emptylist" text="There is currently No User"</empty-list>
      <div *ngFor="let userObser of userObservables">
        <ion-item #emptylist *ngIf="userObser | async as user">   
            <h2>{{user.displayName}}</h2>
            <h3>{{user.email}}</h3>
        </ion-item>
      </div>
```

I want to show the empty list if there is no user & hide it if there is at least one.

I know I can do it using a subscribe method,but I want to use  async pipe also I need to unsubscribe each time I use a subscribe which is really not efficient.

My question is there a way I could create a local variable inside the ion-item the ntest test if it exists outside & therefore use it in the hidden input ? It's just a suggestion I can't really seem to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `else` inside the `ngIf` to display another template if the condition doesn't match:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="userObservables.length > 0; else emptyList">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let user of userObservables">
    <ion-item *ngIf="user | async as user">…</ion-item>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #emptyList>
  <empty-list>…</empty-list>
</ng-template>
```

Note that I also replaced your seemingly unnecessary `div` with a `ng-container` to avoid unnecessary DOM nodes.

---

As a side note to your own suggestion: template references cannot be accessed from outside the template boundary. Structural directives like `*ngIf` and `*ngFor` create their own template, so this becomes a boundary. That's why

```
<h2>{{ ref.innerText }}</h2>
<ng-container>
  <span #ref>Hello, World</span>
</ng-container>
```

will work, but

```
<h2>{{ ref.innerText }}</h2>
<ng-container *ngIf="true">
  <span #ref>Hello, World</span>
</ng-container>
```

won't work.

Comment: Thank you Sir, you rock! Thank you for the lesson too. Just one last question please. Doesn't ng-container create DOM nodes too?

Comment: No, ng-container is only a structural element that will not appear in the DOM at all. It exists exactly for situations like these.